# Is it really so terrible to use global variables?

Tags: objective-c

I've been developing in Objective-C for a long time, mostly games, and lots of people have commented that I frequently use global variables. For example, in my .m file before the `@implementation` I mostly have:

```
BOOL X=0;
int y=1;
NSString *ran;
.
.
.
```

Now, I know I have to use properties, *but* I've found it much clearer for me to use this global variable, and I'm keeping them safe.

Except for the fact that it is not object oriented and/or not acceptable, does it affect any other facet of my app, like processor operation?

In my games I have something like 40 booleans in 1 class that are shared by almost ALL methods. I find it almost impossible to write getter/setter, or use properties for all of them, and I am comfortable with my way. **But is it so wrong?**

Is there another way to deal with many booleans that change in real time frequently, and are shared by all methods?

Is this so terrible to use globals? (I dont need to be considered as good Objective-C user…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjC's not much different from its relatives in this regard.

The problem is that the program is very difficult to use in other contexts. That is, it can be a better choice to reimplement a program entirely rather than making the one with 40 globals reusable (and retesting everything).

40 Booleans for one class is also a llllloooooooot. Read your code -- look for patterns. Make smaller, more easily reusable implementations if you want to get away from the globals. Many devs consider them huge maintenance pains (war stories!). I could easily see myself having trouble trying to understand the program flow of such a program.

Even packing your 40 bools into a C struct and putting an instance of that struct in your ObjC class will be one huge improvement which is simple to implement.

If you have had no problems maintaining these programs, consider it a blessing! …but it will not be a favorite design for other people that will read, extend, or maintain said program.

Comment: @antisanity +1 well played! =)

Comment: but, how can C structure will reduce errors?, its just a classic way to make things look good and smart. if i have a bug in 1 bool, how would a structure help me? still,any method can change this bool to a garbage, and i would not know who it was. isnt it ???

Comment: because the data belongs to an instance, not mutable global state. you also have the option to easily introduce error detection where you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are generally considered bad practice because they lead to coding problems in the long run. If you find yourself able to maintain your code, then go ahead.

But eventually, you'll work on a project big enough where it will cause problems. Why not learn to get along without them now on the easier projects?

Answer (score 1):

As with most development practices, global variables have their place, BUT they reduce how refactorable, readable and debuggable the code is.  Imagine the following scenarios:

1. a program that has an error in one function, but the error is caused by a global variable.  Which other location produced the bad value?  It's nearly impossible to tell.
2. someone who didn't write the code wants to change something, but has no idea where the global values are coming from.  The way to figure out how the program works is to understand EVERY place the global variable is used.  This is much more difficult than if you had simply encapsulated your functionality appropriately.
3. one piece of code is repeated over and over again (every method has access to your global so they all use it, but in just barely different ways).  Requirements change and you need to change how that works slightly.  You now have to change 143 different places in the code.  (one time I had to do this was when the software changed from the English system to metric.  30 different code locations all using DIFFERENT conversion values to do the same thing)

On the other hand, if you have performance issues, there are times when having a global will speed things up, but it's much better to code for readability, refractorability and debuggability and then refactor if necessary for performance.